# Net MAUI error object reference not set to an instance of an object when I prepare model data for post api service

Tags: maui

I´ve trying to prepapre post model data for save information to a external api, in net maui when i prepare de model ClienteCrm has a field Attributte and Contacts both are chield objects array of the root model.. when i run the program give me this error "object reference not set to an instance of an object" this is the code

```
                    try
                    {
                  Models.Attribute atributoscl =  new ()
                    {
                        customAttributeId = 1,
                        value = IdenPersonal

                    };

                    Models.Contact contactoscl = new ()
                    {
                        name = NombresCliente + " " + ApellidosCliente,
                        phone = TelefonoCliente,
                        email = CorreoCliente,
                        isBilling = true,
                        isContact = true
                    };
                    ClientesCrm cliente = new()
                    {
                        organizationId = 1,
                        firstName = NombresCliente,
                        lastName = ApellidosCliente,
                        invoiceAddressSameAsContact = true,
                        isLead = false,
                        clientType = 1,
                        note = NotasCliente,
                        attributes = { atributoscl }, ----> if delete this all fine
                        contacts = {contactoscl},    ----> if delete this all fine
                        addressGpsLat = Convert.ToDouble(Latidud),
                        addressGpsLon = Convert.ToDouble(Longitud)


                    };
```

and this are the models data i use:

```
                    public class BankAccount
                     {
                public int id { get; set; }
              public string accountNumber { get; set; }
               }
          public class Attribute
           {
       public int id { get; set; }
       public int clientId { get; set; }
       public int customAttributeId { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string key { get; set; }
       public string value { get; set; }
       public bool clientZoneVisible { get; set; }
          }

        public class Contact
           {
       public int id { get; set; }
       public int clientId { get; set; }
       public string email { get; set; }
       public string phone { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
       public bool isBilling { get; set; }
       public bool isContact { get; set; }
       public List<Type> types { get; set; }
         }

      public class ClientesCrm

          {
   public int id { get; set; }
       public string userIdent { get; set; }
       public string previousIsp { get; set; }
       public bool isLead { get; set; }
       public int clientType { get; set; }
       public object companyName { get; set; }
       public object companyRegistrationNumber { get; set; }
       public object companyTaxId { get; set; }
       public object companyWebsite { get; set; }
       public string street1 { get; set; }
       public string street2 { get; set; }
       public string city { get; set; }
       public int? countryId { get; set; }
       public int? stateId { get; set; }
       public string zipCode { get; set; }
       public string fullAddress { get; set; }
       public object invoiceStreet1 { get; set; }
       public object invoiceStreet2 { get; set; }
       public object invoiceCity { get; set; }
       public object invoiceStateId { get; set; }
       public object invoiceCountryId { get; set; }
       public object invoiceZipCode { get; set; }
       public bool invoiceAddressSameAsContact { get; set; }
       public string note { get; set; }
       public object sendInvoiceByPost { get; set; }
       public int? invoiceMaturityDays { get; set; }
       public object stopServiceDue { get; set; }
       public object stopServiceDueDays { get; set; }
       public int organizationId { get; set; }
       public object tax1Id { get; set; }
       public object tax2Id { get; set; }
       public object tax3Id { get; set; }
       public DateTime registrationDate { get; set; }
       public object leadConvertedAt { get; set; }
       public object companyContactFirstName { get; set; }
       public object companyContactLastName { get; set; }
       public bool isActive { get; set; }
       public string firstName { get; set; }
       public string lastName { get; set; }
       public string username { get; set; }
       public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
       public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
       public double accountBalance { get; set; }
       public double accountCredit { get; set; }
       public double accountOutstanding { get; set; }
       public string currencyCode { get; set; }
       public string organizationName { get; set; }
       public List<object> bankAccounts { get; set; }
       public List<Tag> tags { get; set; }
       public DateTime? invitationEmailSentDate { get; set; }
       public string avatarColor { get; set; }
       public double? addressGpsLat { get; set; }
       public double? addressGpsLon { get; set; }
       public bool isArchived { get; set; }
       public object generateProformaInvoices { get; set; }
       public bool usesProforma { get; set; }
       public bool hasOverdueInvoice { get; set; }
       public bool hasOutage { get; set; }
       public bool hasSuspendedService { get; set; }
       public bool hasServiceWithoutDevices { get; set; }
       public string referral { get; set; }
       public bool hasPaymentSubscription { get; set; }
       public bool hasAutopayCreditCard { get; set; }
   }

   public class Tag
   {
       public int id { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string colorBackground { get; set; }
       public string colorText { get; set; }
   }

   public class Type
   {
       public int id { get; set; }
         public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Contacts and attributes need to be instantiated with the new keyword

Comment: Please format your code properly, it's very difficult to read your code the way it is presented here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

This should tell us that we are declaring a variable but never instantiating it before using it.

From the code you shared, we could find that you declare `contacts`  and `attributes`  in class `ClientesCrm`, but you didn't initialize values for them before assigning value for them.

So, you can initialize them before assigning values for them in class `ClientesCrm`.

You can refer to the following code:

```
public class ClientesCrm 
{
   // other code

    public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; } =new List<Contact> ();
    public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; } = new List<Attribute> ();   
}
```

And you can also initialize these two variables just as Julian said:

```
    ClientesCrm cliente = new()
{
     // other code
    attributes = new List<Attribute> { atributoscl },
    contacts = new List<Contact> { contactoscl },

};
```

Comment: Hi @Julian, regardless of the code you gave or the code I posted, it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lists cannot be created by simply assigning `{ ... }` to a property or field. A list is an object and as such requires instantiation with the `new` keyword:

```cs
ClientesCrm cliente = new()
{
    organizationId = 1,
    firstName = NombresCliente,
    lastName = ApellidosCliente,
    invoiceAddressSameAsContact = true,
    isLead = false,
    clientType = 1,
    note = NotasCliente,
    attributes = new List<Attribute> { atributoscl },
    contacts = new List<Contact> { contactoscl },
    addressGpsLat = Convert.ToDouble(Latidud),
    addressGpsLon = Convert.ToDouble(Longitud)
};
```